# React Custom Hook run process when prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to React hooks and am attempting to make a custom hook that will concatenate arrays and remove the duplicate objects. I only want the hook to run that process if the prop changes to avoid un-needed processing.

I was attempting to cache concatenated results and use `useMemo` to only run if that changes but that does not work. Obviously, I am missing something with the way `useMemo` works.

I have tried various things mainly around slight tweaks, for example adding arrays to the `useMemo` dependencies as opposed to merged. Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
import * as React from "react";

let merged: any = [];
let result: any = [];

export const useRemoveDuplicateObjects = (arrays: any, value: string) => {
  merged = arrays.flat();

  const key = (item: any) => {
    return item[value];
  };

  const process = () => {
    result = [...new Map(merged.map((item: any) => [key(item), item])).values()];
  };

  React.useMemo(() => {
    if (merged.length) {
      process();
    }
  }, [merged]);

  return [result];
};
```

Comment: You can make use of useEffect internally in this and trigger the logic when props change. Something like this:
export const useRemoveDuplicateObjects = (props) => {
React.useEffect(() => {
// your logic
},[propsThatChange]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things are not done properly here.

For starters, when you pass an array as a second parameter to `useMemo`, React will compare its values with strict equality, i.e. `===`. The comparison
will fail every time because you reassign your `merged` variable
every time the hook is run.

If you want to compare the previous and new values contained by your array, there are 2 ways I can think of:

1. pass directly `merged` as a second parameter instead of putting it
   in an array, this way React would compare the values within it
   directly. I don't know for sure if this would work, since maybe the
   values won't always be in the same order.
2. you could store the "old" value of your array every time the hook
   runs (with a `useState` hook for instance) and compare this old
   value with the new one yourself, and then set a boolean
   accordingly. This way, this boolean can be passed as a second
   parameter within an array to your `useMemo`.

Also, as [the documentation](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) states, useMemo    "returns an expensively
computed value". So, to go along with how it    works, you should get
the "result" value this way :

```
   const result = React.useMemo(() => {
     if (merged.length) {
       return [...new Map(merged.map((item: any) => [key(item), item])).values()]
     }
     return []
   }, merged); // will or won't work, I'd say go with the comparison yourself as stated before
```

Finally, if you only want to return a single value from your hook, there's no need to wrap it in an array, you could just do it this way:

```
return result;
```